# pythonは主に何を作れますか？

Tags: python

pythonを使って何を作れるかを知りたいです。
お願いします。

Comment: 助言や回答を得られ難い、曖昧で範囲の広い質問内容ですね。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を改善してみてください。[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) またこのサイトは??分/時間以内に必ず応答/回答がありますと言うようなサービスを提供するサイトではなく、ユーザー同士が助け合うコミュニティです。必ずしも素早く回答が得られるわけではありません。

Comment: 確かに「主に」という絞り込みの部分が、解答者の主観に委ねている質問の仕方な気がします。なのでもっと具体的なケースに絞った質問が望ましいと思います。例「Python は画像認識に使えますか？」等。

Comment: 何が作れるかといわれれば、何でも作れると思いますが、何に向いてるかというのは、ある程度決まってきます。pythonはインタプリタ型の言語ですから、本格的なアプリ開発よりもちょっとしたプログラムだったり、機械学習等の実験に近いアプリ作成に向くような気がします。本格的なプログラム作成であればC言語、C++、C#等のコンパイル型の言語の方が向くと思います。https://japan.zdnet.com/article/35132550/

Answer (score 2):

Python は、汎用のプログラミング言語です。つまり、何か特定のものを作るのに特化したプログラミング言語ではなく、コンピューターの上で出来ることであればおおよそ何でも出来るように作られたプログラミング言語です。つまり、あなたがコンピューターの上でやりたいことは、それがコンピューターで出来ることなのであれば、ほぼ確実に Python で書くことができます。

もちろん、他のプログラミング言語と比べたときに、Python にも得意・不得意な分野はありますが、プログラミングを始めたばかりの間はそこまで気にする必要は無いでしょう。

どんなことが出来るのか具体的に知るために、例として Python のドキュメントとして書かれている公式チュートリアルの最初の章をご紹介します。この章には以下のように書かれています。

> コンピュータを使っていろいろな作業をしていると、自動化したい作業が出てくるでしょう。たとえば、たくさんのテキストファイルで検索-置換操作を行いたい、大量の写真ファイルを込み入ったやりかたでファイル名を整理して変更したり、などです。ちょっとした専用のデータベースや、何か専用のGUIアプリケーション、シンプルなゲームを作りたいかもしれません。
>
> あなたがプロのソフト開発者として、C/C++/Java ライブラリを扱う必要があるけども、通常の編集/コンパイル/テスト/再コンパイルのサイクルを遅すぎると感じているかもしれません。上記ライブラリのためのテストを書くことにうんざりしているかもしれません。または、拡張言語を持つアプリケーションを書いているなら、そのために新しい言語一式の設計と実装をしたくないでしょう。
>
> Pythonはそんなあなたのための言語です。

（https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/appetite.html より引用）

上の文章に書かれている C、C++、Java というのもまた、汎用のプログラミング言語です。どの言語も殆どなんでも書くことが出来るプログラミング言語になっています。それぞれが Python とどのように異なるのかは短く回答するのが難しいので、Python で何かプログラムを書いてみて慣れてきたら、他のプログラミング言語も書いてみて違いを実感するのも面白いでしょう。